# OSMnx: unlinking tunnels and bridges

Tags: gis, osmnx

As far as I know, Bridges and tunnels can overlap with the above streets in OSMnx (since it is a oversimplified) 
is there any way to unlink bridges and tunnels to get more accurate statistic results.

This feature exists in Space Syntax, in which you can specify which line should be unlinked with which (if they are connected) to achieve more accurate results.

My questions are:
Do OSMnx account for these features? 
If no is there any proposed method to achieve unlinking ?

Comment: What do you mean "unlink"? A tunnel may visually cross the road above it, but they do not intersect in the graph unless there is a node there. OSMnx uses nonplanar graphs to model the street network. See [this article](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.compenvurbsys.2017.05.004) and [this article](https://doi.org/10.1177/2399808318802941).

Comment: @gboeing is there a way to identify instances where edges 'visually' cross but there is no intersection (eg tunnels, bridges etc.) - would this be done with shapely intersects?

Comment: Yes see this paper: https://geoffboeing.com/publications/planarity-street-network-representation/